# RMarkdown not printing Chinese characters in graphs

Tags: r, character-encoding, r-markdown

````
---
title: 

output: 
 pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex

fontsize: 11pt
#mainfont: Calibri
classoption: letter
geometry: left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.6in, bottom=1.25in
subparagraph: yes

header-includes:
- \usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
- \usepackage{setspace}
- \usepackage{tocloft}
- \usepackage{anyfontsize}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{fontspec}
- \usepackage{sectsty}
- \sectionfont{\huge}
- \subsectionfont{\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont}
- \pagestyle{fancy}

- \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
print("中文")
df <- data.frame(
  gp = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 10)),
  y = rnorm(30)
)
ds <- plyr::ddply(df, "gp", plyr::summarise, mean = mean(y), sd = sd(y))

# The summary data frame ds is used to plot larger red points on top
# of the raw data. Note that we don't need to supply `data` or `mapping`
# in each layer because the defaults from ggplot() are used.
ggplot(df, aes(gp, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = ds, aes(y = mean), colour = 'red', size = 3) +
  labs(x = "中文")
```
````

After knitting this file, it seems that the character encoding works fine for the `print` function, but the Chinese characters do not show up in graph labels, and I get errors on character conversions. I am a Mac user. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** This doesn't appear to be a knitr/rmarkdown issue, but rather an issue related to both the font and the output device. I'm not sure of the cause, but the workaround below involves changing the output font (Batang worked for me) and the output device (`pdf` is the default, but changing to `cairo_pdf` or `png` both worked for me).

---

First, identify a font family for which R will render the characters properly. I'm not sure in general how to determine this without trial and error, but in the past I've found that the Symbola and Batang fonts often seem to work with non-English characters and various unicode symbols. You'll need to install the fonts on your computer if you don't have them, and you also might need to [use the `extrafont` package](https://github.com/wch/extrafont) to register the fonts in R. Then you can run the plot code in the console and see if the Chinese characters render properly.

With the Batang font, I found that I was able to output plots to the console with the Chinese characters rendered properly. However, the standard `pdf` device failed to render the characters, whether saving the plot to pdf interactively or when knitting.  Instead I tried the `cairo_pdf` and `png` devices and these both worked. Here's example code (using the same `yaml` as in your question):

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r, dev="cairo_pdf"}
df <- data.frame(
  gp = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 10)),
  y = rnorm(30)
)
ds <- plyr::ddply(df, "gp", plyr::summarise, mean = mean(y), sd = sd(y))

ggplot(df, aes(gp, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = ds, aes(y = mean), colour = 'red', size = 3) +
  labs(x = "中文", title="cairo_pdf device") +
  #theme(axis.title.x=element_text(family="Batang")) # To change font only for x-axis title
  theme(text=element_text(family="Batang", size=15)) 
```

```{r, dev="png", dpi=400}
ggplot(df, aes(gp, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = ds, aes(y = mean), colour = 'red', size = 3) +
  labs(x = "中文", title="png device") +
  theme(text=element_text(family="Batang", size=15)) 
```
````

And here's what the plots look like in the output document:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried using `dev = "cairo_pdf"`, installed the `extrafonts` package, loaded it, added `family = "Batang"` to my ggplot call, and the resulting .pdf now shows some Chinese characters, but others are still not showing up correctly. Is there any other way to fix this? Or any other font you think might work?

Comment: I'm not sure. Hopefully someone will come along who has more systematic information about which fonts can render Chinese characters and how to get them to work with one of the devices that output PDFs. (Just to be certain, after loading `extrafont`, did you run `font_import()`? Unless you start a new R session after that, you might also need to run `loadfonts()`.)

Comment: If you don't get the help you need here, you could try asking this question over at the [RStudio community](https://community.rstudio.com/).

Comment: I didn't, but I happened to try `family = "Heiti SC Light"` and that font worked for me. Thanks!